# unable to find the hyperlink of parent mater page

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web

This hierarchy of master page

```
|--main.master
   |-- index.aspx
   |-- user.master
       |-- login.aspx
```

means master page of `user.master` is `main.master`, master page of login page is `user.master`

I have a loginview control on `main.master` page.

Code for loginview;

```
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
   <AnonymousTemplate>
      [ <a href="~/PageCommon/login.aspx" id="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" color="#87cfe6">Log In</a> ]
   </AnonymousTemplate>
   <LoggedInTemplate>
      Welcome <span class="bold">
      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" ForeColor="PeachPuff" Font-Size="Larger" ToolTip="MyHome"  runat="server"> <asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></asp:HyperLink>
      </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      [
       <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" ForeColor="#87cfe6" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/PageCommon/index.aspx" />
      ]
   </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Now in code behind of login page I want to access the hyperlink of login view to change the navigate url of that hyperlink. But I am unable to access the hyperlink.

I used this code to access the hyperlink

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   HyperLink rdirect = (HyperLink)Master.FindControl("HyperLink1");

   int index = utype.SelectedIndex;

   if (index == 0)
   {
      rdirect.NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl("~/PageUser/MyProfile.aspx");
   }
   else if (index == 1)
   {
      rdirect.NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl("~/PageAdmin/MyProfile.aspx");
   }
}
```

Master page of login page is `user.master`, and master page for `user.master` is `main.master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all to access any control in master page(which is inside ContentPlaceHolder) one way is, first access the ContentPlaceHolder than in this CPH(ContentPlaceHolder) find you desired control.(if its on root i.e outsede CPH than access it without finding CPH)

**Case if LoginView is on root of Main.master:**

```
 LoginView logInView = (LoginView)this.Master.Master.FindControl("HeadLoginView");
 HyperLink hyp2 = (HyperLink)logInView.FindControl("HyperLink1");
```

**Case if LoginView inside ContentPlaceHolder of Main.master:**

In Your scenario you have nested master pages..so if you define like this:
asuming that in you main.master their is only one ContentPlaceHolder Id = ContentPlaceHolder1

```
ContentPlaceHolder User_cph1 = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
```

It will give you the User.master ContentPlaceHolder as their is only one CPH in masterpage(its assumption)

so one way is to define new contentplaceholde("ContentPlaceHolder2") in main.master and put you LoginView Control in it, than use this code :(purpose of defining new CPH is only to validate that this CPH not being used by user.master)

```
ContentPlaceHolder Main_cph2 = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder2");
        LoginView logInView = (LoginView)Main_cph2.FindControl("HeadLoginView");
        HyperLink hyp2 = (HyperLink)logInView.FindControl("HyperLink1");
```

it will first find CPH in Main.Master

than Find HeadLoginView in CPH

than find HyperLink  in HeadLoginView

Hope it is some cleared to you :)

Comment: sir my loginview is outside of CPH. so i wrotr this code on login.aspx.cs page 
LoginView logInView = (LoginView)this.Master.Master.FindControl("HeadLoginView");
HyperLink rdirect = (HyperLink)logInView.FindControl("HyperLink1");
 i uses break point to see it is returning , it is returning null . so i am getting the exception : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: By the way i have tested this code..can you tell me which thing is null ? did you found LoginView ?  while debugging first hover your mouse on Master check is it null ? than hove on 2nd master than tell me..aslo check that did you added any attribute to your pages ..give me your email i'll send you sample code

Comment: yes sir i am getting loginview and master both are null.
amitverma0511@gmail.com
can i get your email please . i'll send you my complete code.

Comment: sir i have sent you mail

Comment: Boy may i ask you where is the nested master page scenario in you code.!!! there is noting like that..simple use  LoginView logInView = (LoginView)this.Master.FindControl("HeadLoginView");

Comment: Your only problem was only that you were searching HyperLink directly from MasterPage..but you must had to find LoginView first than in this LoginView find hyperLink..Hope now problem is solved. Please change the SUBJECT OF QUESTION..ITS NOTHING TO DO WITH YOUR PROBLEM..:D

Answer (score 0):

It is because you try to access a control of a master page of a master page.

This:

```
(HyperLink)Master.FindControl("HyperLink1");
```

does not work because you try to get the control from the master page, but the control **is in the master page of the master page**. I think you should have a property in the code-behind of `user.master` which returns this control and you should use that property in the code-behind of `login.aspx`.